# How to verify interactions within the class under test?

Tags: java, unit-testing, groovy, mocking, spock

```java
// class under specification
public class TeamService {

  // method under specification
  public void deleteTeam(String id) {
     /* some other calls */
     this.moveAssets(team) // calls method within the class under spec. 
  }

  // I would like to stub / mock this method
  public void moveAssets(Team team){
    // logic
  } 
  
}
```

**Spock Spec**

```java
def deleteTeam(){
   given: 
   TeamService teamService = new TeamService()

   when: 'I delete the team'
   teamService.deleteTeam()
   
   then: 'I want to check that moveAssets gets called(team resources going to be preserved 
and that deleteTeam (external class that deletes the team) gets called (has no issues here)'

   1 * teamService.moveAssets(id) >> {} //See Q1
/* 
Q1: I want to test that this call is made 
but currently it does not count as interaction for some reason so I get an error. 
From what I read you can't stub the calls unless the class is mocked -
 
but here I do have an important need to check on the method within the class under specification 
(that is not mocked). What are my options?

I know I can in theory move moveAssets to some other class,
which I can then mock and accomplish it but that does not feel right. 
*/
}
```

So in Spock's Spec for this class, TeamService is the class under specification, and the deleteTeam is a method under specification.

**The problem**
I get an error 0 invocations for the moveAssets method.
I want to be able to stub / test the moveAssets method there is not a lot of info on how to accomplish that.
I don't want to relocate the moveAssets to anotherClass (so I could then mock it).
Any guidance is appreciated.

There has to be some better way of dealing with this scenario.

---

**Summary:**

How do you test a 'Class Under Specification' teamServices.moveAssets()) method, that is being called from the 'Method Under Specification (teamServices.deleteTeam())'?

---

https://github.com/spockframework/spock/discussions/1346

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like you noticed already, you can only check interactions on a mocked object type, i.e. mock, stub or spy. The latter, a [**spy**](https://spockframework.org/spock/docs/2.0/all_in_one.html#Spies), is what you need in this case, i.e. something like:

```java
TeamService teamService =
  Spy(constructorArgs: [mockedInjectedService1, mockedInjectedService2])
```

Here is an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q67950174

class Team {
  String id
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q67950174

class TeamService {
  def dep1, dep2

  TeamService(dep1, dep2) {
    this.dep1 = dep1
    this.dep2 = dep2
  }

  boolean moveAssets(Team team) {
    println "Moving assets for team $team"
    return false
  }

  void deleteTeam(String id) {
    Team team = findTeamById(id)
    moveAssets(team)
    delete(team)
  }

  Team findTeamById(String id) {
    println "Searching for team $team"
    return new Team(id: id)
  }

  void delete(Team team) {
    println "Deleting team $team"
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q67950174

import spock.lang.Specification

class TeamServiceTest extends Specification {
  def deleteTeam() {
    given:
    Team teamDocument = new Team(id: "dummy")
    String id = "foo"
    def mockedInjectedService1 = "X"
    def mockedInjectedService2 = "Y"
    TeamService teamService = Spy(constructorArgs: [mockedInjectedService1, mockedInjectedService2])

    when: 'I delete the team'
    teamService.deleteTeam(id)

    then: 'I want to check that moveAssets gets called(team resources going to be preserved'
    1 * teamService.findTeamById(id) >> teamDocument
    1 * teamService.moveAssets(teamDocument) >> true
  }
}
```

Comment: Good example, I'm only confused why you added two additional mocks as dependencies, while the OPs `TeamService`  doesn't have any constructor args.

Comment: I had those dependencies when I originally asked the questions, then realized they are not quite relevant to the question. In the original code, I do have mocks as dependencies. Sorry for any confusion, folks. Really appreciate the feedback and help.

Comment: @LeonardBrünings, because I answered [this version](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/67950174/4) of the question, trying to be nice and use as much of the original code as I could in order to make it easier for the OP, who unfortunately was unwise (I am trying to avoid another adjective here) enough to simply modify the question after it was already answered, creating confusion. Anyway, at least my answer now shows how to use `constructorArgs`, which is what the OP actually needs.

Comment: @kriegaex, let's keep it professional. My only intent was to make my question more clear since I did not manage to do it in my initial question. I honestly tried to do my best to the best of my knowledge.